# CAN FD Bit Stuffing on the boundary between DATA and CRC fields

Tags: can

CAN FD specification states that there shall be a fixed STUFF-BIT before the first bit of the CRC SEQUENCE. However, there is an edge case according to this statement when the DATA field ends with a stuff bit.

I think there shouldn't be an extra fixed-stuff bit in CRC field and the transmitter CAN node should use this stuff bit as the first fixed-stuff bit in the CRC field.

What is the expected behavior in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this issue is explained in CAN FD ISO11898-1:2015 spec as follows:

*... there shall be only the fixed stuff bit, there shall not be two consecutive stuff bits.*